# Ramification of local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be finite field, $E=K((x))$ and $F=K((x^n))$, that is $F$ is field of formal laurent series in $x^n$. I know that $E\cong F$ (because you can consider $x\rightarrow x^n$ )

I want to prove if $L/F$ is any field extension of degree $n$ such that $e(L/F)=n$ then $L\cong E$ as $F$-algebra.
Thanks

Comment: It is not true as stated. For example, suppose $-1$ has no square root in $K$ (e.g. $K=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$), $n=2$, and that $L=F(\sqrt{-x^2})$. Since $E$ contains no square root of $-x^2$, $L$ and $E$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @user8268 It is not clear for me that $e(L/F)=2$. Can you explain why  $e(L/F)=2$?

Comment: $v(\sqrt{-x^2})=v(x^2)/2$ ($v$ is the valuation), so $e(L/F)\geq2$

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

1. Use the classification of locally compact fields of positive characteristic: every such field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$ for some finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ (c.f. e.g. Corollary 5 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter5.pdf)).
2. Use the fact that the extension is totally ramified to figure out the size of the constant subfield.
3. Think about what happens to a uniformizing element in a totally ramified extension.